# There exists a pair of positive ints $(m,n)$ such that $(m,n$ and $m+n)$ are all perfect squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory, predicate-logic

The only thing I figured to do was just to express these three guys..

$m =a^2$ ,$ n=b^2 $, and $m+n = a^2 + b^2$

Comment: Try $m=3^2, n=4^2, (m+n)=5^2$.

Comment: So, $a^2+b^2 = c^2$ - now, where have I seen that before?

Comment: Oh man Pythagoras was a step ahead of me. Because this is an existential (something), just to find one case proves the whole thing, I see. Cheers.

Comment: One note - your second line in the post says $m+n=a^2+b^2$. It should be $m+n=c^2$. It's saying that $m+n$ is a perfect square, not that it's the sum of the other two squares (it's always the sum of the other two squares, no matter the numbers, but it's not always a perfect square itself).

Answer (score 1):

There are an infinite number of those. Consider the recursive definition of $a_k = k^2 $:
$$x_{k+1} =x_k + 2k + 1$$
or in other words:
$$ (k+1)^2 = k^2 + (2k + 1)$$

You can prove that for every $n$ odd square there's at least one $m$ even square number such that $m+n$ is also a square:

$$n = 2\sqrt m + 1$$
$$m = (\frac{n-1}2)^2$$